# Import to google sheets of the dollar exchange rate to the georgian lari

Tags: google-sheets

Help with the formula
I need import to google sheets of the dollar exchange rate to the georgian lari from the National Bank of Georgia
https://nbg.gov.ge/en/monetary-policy/currency
Thanks.

I know how to import from Google finance (=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDGEL")), but the course there is not quite accurate. You need it from the national bank or the most accurate from other places.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,importxml("https://nbg.gov.ge/en/monetary-policy/currency","//div[contains(@class,'182984682')]"),
     index(Σ,xmatch("1US Dollar",Σ)+1))
```

***OR***

```js
=importxml("https://nbg.gov.ge/en/monetary-policy/currency","//div[41]/div[1]/div[1]")
```

[image]

Comment: 1 method does not work, 2 does not suit me. I need to have a number in one cell.

Comment: Share a test sheet showcasing the error scenario of method 1 so that I can check on it directly.

Comment: If you want just the number in method 2, use `index()` or `choosecols()` to only pick the 3rd column cell of the output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lg2P6xKeurljkoKGtfINCf8s7N2iEkWboBw-F-ZAL20/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The sheet of OP uses [semicolon based convention](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/) & so the issue with the comma based formula(s) shared above

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about the following approach? When I saw the HTML, I confirmed that the values for the table are included in 1st loaded HTML as JSON data. So, in this answer, the result value is retrieved from the JSON data. In this case, in order to parse the JSON data, Google Apps Script is used.

Please copy and paste the following sample script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save the script.

#### Sample script:

```js
function SAMPLE(searchCode = "USD") {
  const url = "https://nbg.gov.ge/en/monetary-policy/currency";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const str = res.getContentText().match(/<script id\="__NEXT_DATA__" type\="application\/json">([\w\s\S]*?)<\/script>/);
  if (str) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(str[1]);
    const ar = obj.props.initialProps.pageProps.currentCurrencies.currencies;
    const o = ar.find(({ code }) => code == searchCode);
    if (o) {
      return o.rateFormated;
    }
  }
  return "No value";
}
```

#### Testing:

When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE()`. By this, the following result is obtained as the current result. In this sample, as the default code, `USD` is retrieved. But, you can select the code like `=SAMPLE("JPY")`

[image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)
- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

The data on that site is created dynamically and cannot be imported using built-in Google functions (such as IMPORTXML, etc).